# Debian /bin/sh in a Docker container never seems to look at .profile

Tags: debian, profile, dash

I can not seem to get [dash](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dash/dash.1.en.html) to look at $HOME/.profile:

```
pedz@Peace:s001 ~[S:hatred] % docker exec -it hatred-web-1 dash -i
# cat $HOME/.profile
PROOF=true; export PROOF
PATH=/hatred/bin:$PATH; export PATH
# env | sort
BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=hatred
LANG=C.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/hatred
RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=ca10d017f8a1b6d247556622c841fc56b90c03b1803f87198da1e4fd3ec3bf2a
RUBY_MAJOR=3.1
RUBY_VERSION=3.1.2
TERM=xterm
# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 14:28 ?        00:00:01 puma 5.6.5 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [hatred]
root       152     0  0 14:54 pts/0    00:00:00 dash -i
root       161   152  0 14:54 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
# set
BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG='/usr/local/bundle'
BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING='1'
GEM_HOME='/usr/local/bundle'
HOME='/root'
HOSTNAME='hatred'
IFS='   
'
LANG='C.UTF-8'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
PPID='0'
PS1='# '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/hatred'
RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256='ca10d017f8a1b6d247556622c841fc56b90c03b1803f87198da1e4fd3ec3bf2a'
RUBY_MAJOR='3.1'
RUBY_VERSION='3.1.2'
TERM='xterm'
_='-ef'
# lsb_release -c
Codename:   bullseye
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
#
```

Note that PROOF is not in env's output and PATH does not have `/hatred/bin` prepended to it.

Comment: Shells typically only read `.profile` as a login shell. Shells started by `docker exec` are not considered login shells. If you `docker exec ... dash -l` it will run your `.profile`.

Comment: Hmm... Ok.  That seems to be correct.  The dash documentation says to use `-i` in the Invocation part of the man page to make it "interactive".  Curiously, if `-l` is used, then the PATH to /usr/local/bundler/bin which I guess was set by one of the parent images is lost.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I sent this question to the Debian users mailing list.  It was pointed out to me that the text **does** describe the behavior correctly.  Here are a few things that tripped me up:

The text says "When first starting, the shell inspects argument 0, and if it begins with a dash ‘-’, the shell is **also** considered a login shell." (emphasis added by me).

I misunderstood the reason for the `also`.  And, indeed, it isn't clear why it is there.

To me, it would be much clearer if that sentence started a new paragraph because the topic has changed from an interactive shell to a login shell.  It would be clearer to leave out the `also`, and it would be clearer to mention the `-l` option at that point.

All this to say, as the comments pointed out, to read `$HOME/.profile`, you need to either specify the `-l` option or make $0 begin with a dash.